# What encoding is like "\u0441\"?

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding

I'm scraping from an API with Python requests library and a large percentage of the JSON output is producing this sort of thing:

```
{
  "a": "\u0441\u0432\u0430\u0434\u0435\u0431\u043d\u043e\u0435\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0435", 
  "b": "weddingstyle", 
  "id": "\u0441\u0432\u0430\u0434\u0435\u0431\u043d\u043e\u0435\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0435#weddingstyle"
}
```

What encoding is this `\u0441\u0432\u0430\u0434\u0435\u0431\u043d\u043e\u0435\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0435`?

Comment: It's JSON: https://json.org/

Comment: And it decodes it `свадебноеплатье`.  Apparently, the API is coded to represent all non-ASCII characters in strings with escape sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These characters seem like the characters from Cyrillic script - used commonly for Slavic text.

[Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) says

> The Cyrillic script (/sɪˈrɪlɪk/) is a writing system used for various alphabets across Eurasia and is used as the national script in various Slavic-, Turkic- and Persian-speaking countries in Eastern Europe, the Caucasus, Central Asia, and North Asia.
>
> Cyrillic script spread throughout the East Slavic and some South Slavic territories, being adopted for writing local languages, such as Old East Slavic. Its adaptation to local languages produced a number of Cyrillic alphabets, discussed hereafter.

To decode the characters, please check the link:
https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en

[Cyrillic-conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c4aG.png)